# Trouble with having my `welcome.blade.php` recognizing Vue imported inside of my Nuxt.js folder

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, nuxt.js

I am working with `Nuxt.js` on my `Laravel` project. I needed to combine both of them together since they come with a boilerplate when installing them into my project.

I was able to get almost everything working up to the point where I needed my `welcome.blade.php` to be able to read my `index.vue` component that was created inside of my `resources/nuxt/pages` folder.

Currently, the problem I am getting is that I have an "unexpected identifier on line 1 of my `public/App.js`" file where I import vue.

`Import Vue from 'vue'`

SO. How things get compiled is through my `yarn run dev-nuxt` that I modified in my `package.json` (simplified | only showing what I think I need to | i'd be happy to show more upon request)

```
    {
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-nuxt": "nuxt",
    },
```

Prior to that I was running `yarn run dev`

```
"dev": "npm run development",
"development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
```

which would look at webpack.mix.js. When running `yarn run dev` my terminal would return these errors:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '~/components/Logo.vue' in 'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\META+LAB\iSTART\resources\pages'
 @ ./resources/pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--4-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./resources/pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&) 28:0-41 32:10-14
 @ ./resources/pages/index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
 @ ./resources/pages/index.vue
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/assets/app.scss
```

So then I also realized that my webpack.mix.jshas no references to my `nuxt.config.js` (simplified | only showing what I think I need to | i'd be happy to show more upon request)

```js
    const pkg = require('./package')
    const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
      mode: 'spa',
      /*
      ** srcDir points to where nuxt will be compiled by yarn nuxt-dev
      */
      srcDir: 'resources/',
      /*
      ** buildDir is where my nuxt code will be compiled to 
      */
      buildDir: 'public/js/',

      ** Nuxt.js modules
      */
      modules: [,
        // Doc: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/
        'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
        'nuxt-babel'
      ],
```

which has a reference to my .babelrc which should be compiling my vue into my `App.js` (simplified | only showing what I think I need to | i'd be happy to show more upon request)

```js
    {
      "env": {
        "test": {
          "presets": [
            [
              "@babel/preset-env",
              {
                "targets": {
                  "node": "current"
                }
              }
            ],
            "@nuxt/babel-preset-app"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

So I'm not sure why I am getting this error. Is it possible that I have either my `nuxt.config.js` or my `.babelrc` set up improperly?

This is how my `welcome.blade.php` looks:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <title>Laravel</title>

            <!-- Fonts -->
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="app">
                 <index></index>
            </div>
            <script src="/js/App.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

When compiling nuxt through `yarn run dev-nuxt` as declared in my `package.json` above, I get a port that shows my `index.vue` component perfectly, however I do not have access to this component when running `php artisan serve`

I have a feeling that I did not configure something properly, or that I need to install more packages?

For reference here is my whole `package.json`

```js
    "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.27",
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jest": "^23.6.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.2",
        "vue-jest": "^3.0.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
        "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
        "nuxt": "^2.4.0",
        "vue-loader": "^15.6.2"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think on the html level, you still need to initialize Vue on `#app` in a script tag ... cause I don't think Vue is initialized , basically :

```js
let app = new Vue({el : "#app'});
```

Comment: I tried that and it still didn't work either. However I do get a little closer to solving my problem when doing that

Comment: what does console log reveal ?

Comment: I get the same error: "unexpected identifier" and then a bunch of errors basically saying it can't trans-compile the vue instances that came with Nuxt.js. I'll post the error in my post above

Comment: This is also with running `yarn run dev` which as mentioned above hits `webpack.mix.js` which will trans-compile my app.js that has my instantiation of vue

Comment: You can find it by `ctrl + f` "Module Not found"

Comment: Laravel Mix + Nuxt, you should probably google about it. Cause it loads app.js , so you need to register Nuxt inside there